# Regex for multiple patterns in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a column in pandas Dataframe that will be in one of below patterns:

- `A1_1__Textvalue` (numbers can be of single or two-digit)
- `A1__Textvalue`
  How do I apply regex pattern to remove all characters before `Text`?

I tried

```py
df1.replace(to_replace=[r"^A/d_/d__"], value=" ", regex=True, inplace=True)
```

This works only for single-digit after initial 'A'. It doesn’t work for `A22_2__` or `A3_33_`

Comment: Surely you mean `\d` and not `/d`?

Answer (score 0):

`\d` matches a single digit; you need to add a quantifier like `\d+` to match multiple digits (one or more) or a specific range like `\d{1,23}` to match between 1 and 23 digits.

`value=" "` replaces the match with a single space; to completely remove the match, use `value=""`.